# What is the difference between (*ptr).f() and ptr->f()?

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ - Difference between (*). and ->?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470255/c-difference-between-and)

What is the difference between this:

```
(*ptr).f();
```

and this:

```
ptr->f();
```

in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) where the ptr is a pointer to C++ class which has a function `f`?

Comment: The only difference is that the compiler will transform `ptr->f()` into `(*ptr).f()` (aka, it's just a shortcut).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `ptr` is a normal pointer, then both are equivalent. `ptr->f` is a short-cut to dereference the pointer (equivalent to `(*ptr)`) and access the member of the dereferenced object (equivalent to `.f`).

If `ptr` is a class that overloads `operator->` and `operator*`, then they will each call different operator overloads, and so could have different behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference at all. `(*ptr).f();` is the uglier way to do this.

<sub>Actually, if `ptr` is some smart pointer and its `operator*` and `operator->` are overloaded and execute some side-effects, then you may have a problem with this. But this is really, really bad thing to do. It's as evil as `#define true false`</sub>

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you should (almost) never define operators in a way that violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from stylistic/typing differences, there is no difference. It's exactly the same as `(*ptr).member = 7;` vs `ptr->member = 7;` when using a pointer to a structure or class.