# C++ member access/indirection operator equivalence

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

I was looking at the C++ standard regarding member reference operators (the unary `*` dereferencing operator, the `->` member accessor operator) as well as many other related questions:

[C++ - Difference between (*). and ->?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470255/c-difference-between-and)

[ptr->hello(); /* VERSUS */ (*ptr).hello();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447543/ptr-hello-versus-ptr-hello)

[C++ pointers difference between * and ->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681926/c-pointers-difference-between-and)

I saw that most answers stated that `p->m` is syntactic sugar for `(*p).m` as defined by the C++ Standard (5.2.5, paragraph 2):

> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`

Many comments also noted that because `operator*` and `operator->` are overloadable in classes, they should be overloaded uniformly to ensure consistent behavior.

These statements seem to contradict each other: if (as per the standard) `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`, then what would be the purpose of overloading `operator->` (as is permitted by the standard)?

Simpler stated, are these two parts of the standard in conflict, or am I misunderstanding the Standard?
Does the `E1->E2` equivalence transformation to `(*(E1)).E2` apply to all complete types or only to built in ones?

Comment: See point 3 of clause 5, "Clause 5 defines the effects of operators when applied to types for which they have not been overloaded."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion from `E1 -> E2` to `(*(E1)).E2` only applies to raw pointer types. For class types, `E1 -> E2` evaluates to `(E1).operator->().E2`, which potentially might recursively expand out even more copies of `operator->` if the return type of `operator->` is not itself a pointer type. You can see this by creating a type that supports `operator*` but not `operator->` and trying to use the arrow operator on it; you'll get an error that `operator->` is undefined.

As a follow-up, it's common to implement `operator ->` in terms of `operator *` in a way that makes the semantics of `->` match the semantics for pointers. You often see things like this:

```
PointerType ClassType::operator-> () const {
    return &**this;
}
```

This expression is interpreted as

```
&(*(*this)),
```

meaning "take this object (`*this`), dereference it (`*(*this)`), and get the address of what you find (`&(*(*this))`.)." Now, if you use the rule that `E1 -> E2` should be equivalent to `(*(E1)).E2`, you can see that you end up getting something equivalent.

Comment: This is a great explanation! I never realized the resolution to a raw pointer before the equivalent expression conversion. The example was a very helpful illustration.